# Entity Framework Core - DbContext SaveChanges Issue from drop-down list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm new to using EF as well as ASP.NET Core. I'm working on a simple web application and I am getting an error when I go to save a new record.  When the `DbContext.SaveChanges()` gets called, I get an error that states:

> "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ContactTypes' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

I understand exactly what the message means and why I am getting it.  Based on that message, EF is trying to insert a record into the `ContactTypes` table and since that table does not allow inserting the primary key value, it gives that error.  The `ContactTypes` table has a set of fixed records that will likely not change.  The records from the `ContactTypes` table are used to populate a drop-down list (HTML select element).  That functionality works fine and when the user selects the desired option and then tries to save the parent (Client) record, EF wants to insert a new record into the `ContactTypes` table, which is unnecessary.  When EF Core created the database, a "ContactTypeID" field was added to the `Clients` table, which should hold the ID for the ContactType selected.

[image: Client Database Table]

Below are my classes:

```cs
public class Client
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public Person Person { get; set; }// = new Person();
    public ContactType ContactType { get; set; }// = new ContactType();//Client or Inquiry

    //other properties removed for brevity
}

public class ContactType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string ContactTypeDescription { get; set; } //typically either Client or Inquiry
}

public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "N/A";

    [Required, StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = "N/A";

    //other properties removed for brevity

}
```

Here's my `OnModelCreating` method:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //setup our relationships
    modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
        .HasOne(c => c.Person);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
        .HasOne(c => c.ContactType)
        .WithMany();


    //create our other supporting tables and initialize data if necessary
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("People");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasData(new Person { ID = 1, FirstName = "N/A", LastName = "N/A" });


    modelBuilder.Entity<ContactType>()
                .ToTable("ContactTypes"); 

    modelBuilder.Entity<ContactType>().HasData(new ContactType { ID = 1, ContactTypeDescription = "Not Specified" },
                                                new ContactType { ID = 2, ContactTypeDescription = "Inquiry" },
                                                new ContactType { ID = 3, ContactTypeDescription = "Client" });

}
```

Here is my markup for the HTML select

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label for="type" class="form-label stacked-justify-left">Contact Type</label>

    <select asp-for="Client.ContactType.ID" asp-items="Model.ContactTypes" class="form-control" style="height:40px; width:180px">
        <option value="">-- Select Type --</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Client.ContactType.ID" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"></span>
</div>
```

So I'm not sure how to tell EF Core not to add records to the `ContactTypes` table when saving the Client entity information. If other information is needed, please ask and I will supply. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I rolled back your revision. You shouldn't change the question that drastically if you received answers. Ask a new question if new issues arise after getting helpful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `Client` class should be:

```cs
public class Client
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public Person Person { get; set; }// = new Person();

    public int ContactTypeID { get; set; }

    public ContactType ContactType { get; set; }// = new ContactType();//Client or Inquiry
}

public class ContactType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string ContactTypeDescription { get; set; } //typically either Client or Inquiry

    public IList<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
            .HasOne(c => c.ContactType)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ContactTypeId);
```

And modify the View as:

```
<select asp-for="Client.ContactTypeID" asp-items="Model.ContactTypes" class="form-control" style="height:40px; width:180px">
    <option value="">-- Select Type --</option>
</select>
<span asp-validation-for="Client.ContactTypeID" class="text-danger font-weight-bold"></span>
```

---

**Reference**

1. [Conventions in Entity Framework Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/conventions-in-ef-core.aspx)
2. [One-to-Many Relationship Conventions in Entity Framework Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-many-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx)